# How to use arrays in my custom adapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have custom listview adapter to display two rows of data.
I can set this data into `String[] name = {some values};`, but I can't create listview from arrays.
Here is the code of activity:

```
public class ListAction extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    String[] data = { "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ",
        "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ",
        "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ",
        "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ",
        "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ",
        "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data " };
    String[] data2 = { "Sample User Data 2", "Sample User Data 2",
            "Sample User Data 2", "Sample User Data 2", "Sample User Data 2",
            "Sample User Data 2", "Sample User Data 2", "Sample User Data 2",
            "Sample User Data 2", "Sample User Data 2", "Sample User Data 2",
            "Sample User Data 2", "Sample User Data 2", "Sample User Data 2",
            "Sample User Data 2", "Sample User Data 2" };

    ListView myList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        myList.setAdapter((ListAdapter) new MyCustomAdapter());
        myList.setCacheColorHint(0);

        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                String itemname = new Integer(position).toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(ListAction.this, ViewClient.class);

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("fileName", itemname);
                intent.putExtras(b);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.length;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row;

            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            TextView textLabel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            textLabel.setText(data[position]);

            TextView textLabel2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            textLabel2.setText(data2[position]);

            return (row);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to fill listview with data from arrays, for example like this:
`String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);` but I only get NullPointer at this row.
Please, help.

---

Log:

```
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.ListAction}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at com.example.ListAction.<init>(ListAction.java:25)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
04-06 23:35:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(11420):    ... 11 more
```

25th row is `String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);`

Comment: please share XML file and starck strace when using `String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);`

Comment: @zylootino I've added log, please look. Layout file contains two textviews and two arrays consists of two items.

Comment: what happens there? at com.example.ListAction.<init>(ListAction.java:25)

Comment: I press the button on MainActivity which starts ListAction activity and as I wrote 25 line is array of strings.

Comment: but this line is not in the code... you replaced it with java arrays? Make sure String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories); is in onCreate() after super.onCreate()

Comment: @zylootino Thank you very much. As always the solution was much simpler than question. Please, write your comment as an answer. I'll upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);` is in `onCreate()` after `super.onCreate()`. The context must be instantiated before you call its methods.

Answer (score 1):

see this complete example given here....

http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/dynamic-custoized-list-view-in-android.html

[image]

Comment: And how can I change this to arrays? `gtuMcaBean.add(new GtuMcaBean("1 First", "1 Last", "1 Birthdate"));` Please, help.

Comment: pass <String> instead of <GtuMcaBean>

Comment: But there are 3 values. Please, can you write in what way should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing your arrays to the adapter. Pass it using a constructor or use an ArrayAdapter. Try this tutorial.

http://www.shubhayu.com/android/listview-with-arrayadapter-and-customized-items

Comment: But how can I change this to arrays? comment = new CommentObject();
     `comment.senderName = "Susie";
     comment.commentText = "The boy is nuts";
     comment.senderPhoto = "susie.png";
     comment.link = "http://www.iclickedonsusie.com";     
     commentList.add(comment);` Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your array into your custom adapter or else it will not know the correct size and position will not work